# Values for th:field attributes in checkbox

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have table with datas from database (insert dynamically). In one column I insert checkbox. Now I want to select one of them and send to next form (I select one product and send properties to another form. In this form should be displayed properties only the select product). But I don't know what kind of value insert in th:field="*{}". I tried many solutions but doesn't work. My html form with all products table:

```
<form action="/oferta/zamow" th:action="@{/oferta/zamow}"
      th:object="${oferta}" method="post">

    <table border="1" id="display-data">
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>author</td>
            <td>rok</td>
            <td>cena</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="produkt, pozycja : ${oferta}">
            <td th:text="${pozycja.count}"></td>
            <td><span th:text="${produkt.tytul}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${produkt.autor}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${produkt.rok}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${produkt.cena}"></span></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="zamow"/>
                <!-- <a th:href="@{/zamowienie}">zamow</a> -->
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>zamow</label>
                <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{produkt}" th:value="${produkt}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Form to display select product:

```
<form action="/zamowienie/zam" th:action="@{/zamowienie/zam}"
      th:object="${zamowienie}" method="post">

    <table border="1" id="display-data">
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2">twoje zamowienie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>tytul</td>
            <td><span th:text="${produkt.tytul}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>autor</td>
            <td><span th:text="${produkt.autor}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>rok</td>
            <td><span th:text="${produkt.rok}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cena</td>
            <td><span th:text="${produkt.cena}"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data zlozenia zamowienia</td>
            <td><span th:text="${datazam}"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure if this is the answer you seek, but you can find an example at http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Thymeleaf-Spring3.html#checkbox-fields.

Here is a simple example to illustrate how to use a checkbox in Thymeleaf with Spring MVC.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showForm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model) {
  List<String> allItems = new ArrayList<String>();
  allItems.add("value1");
  allItems.add("value2");
  allItems.add("value3");
  model.addAttribute("allItems", allItems);

  Foo foo = new Foo();
  List<String> checkedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
  // value1 will be checked by default.
  checkedItems.add("value1");
  foo.setCheckedItems(checkedItems);
  model.addAttribute("foo", foo);

  ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/processForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute(value="foo") Foo foo) {
  // Get value of checked item.
  List<String> checkedItems = foo.getCheckedItems();
  ...
}
```

html:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/processForm}" th:object="${foo}" method="post">
  <div th:each="item : ${allItems}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${item}" />
    <label th:text="${item}">example</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Foo.java:

```
public class Foo {
  private List<String> checkedItems;

  public List<String> getCheckedItems() {
    return checkedItems;
  }

  public void setCheckedItems(List<String> checkedItems) {
    this.checkedItems = checkedItems;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the thymeleaf spring integration docs.

All th:field are mapped against the command object. Thats why you need the *{} expression.

One thing the template engine is not able to do (yet) is mapping fields inside a loop directly. So you cannot use the *{} approach to reference the produkt variable from the loop.

What you have to do is use the index of the th:each expression and build a property accessor with a pre-evaluated expression for the index.

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{produkts[__${index}__].checked" />
```

You do not need the th:value, th:field is taking care of it. (Except if you want to superseed it)