# How to get checked boxes in a Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have got a `html` page (with `Thymeleaf`):

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/changeme}">
  <fieldset>
    <table style="width: 500px">
      <tr th:each="esfield : ${esfields}">
        <td>
          <div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="optionsMulti"
                th:text="${esfield}" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="submit"
            class="btn btn-xs btn-primary margin10-right paddingNew"
            name="save">Calculate!</button>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

When I click `Calculate!` it goes to my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changeme", params = { "save" })
public String save(final ModelMap m) {

    m.addAttribute("centers", /*params*/);
    return "clustering";
}
```

I would like to get information about `checked boxes` in my controller?

How can I do that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @ruhungry you may possibly use `@RequestParam String[] optionsMulti`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Values for th:field attributes in checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692941/values-for-thfield-attributes-in-checkbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two options :

- either you use a different name for each checkbox
- or you use spring tag `<form:checkbox>` instead of native `<checkbox>`

If you don't posted data will not allow you to know exactly what boxes were actually checked (excepted in cases all and none)

With the  approach, you should use in your controller a `@ModelAttribute` annotated object containing a `List<Boolean>` and spring will automagically populate it with the values of your checkboxes.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changeme", params = { "save" })
public String save(@ModelAttribute BoxesForm form, final ModelMap m) {
    // do what you need with form.getCheckboxes() ...
    m.addAttribute("centers", /*params*/);
    return "clustering";
}

public class BoxesForm {
    List<Boolean> checkboxes;
    // getter and setter omitted ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I changed my `controller` and I changed a little bit html view: `<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes" th:text="${esfield}" />`. Now, in my controller I can see a list of `true`. I would like to be able to say, which elements have been checked. Could you explain me how to do that?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you cannot. You have to use `<form:checkbox/>` to ask spring to give you a list of all checkboxes either true or false

Comment: I found a solution on SO. I marked my post as a duplicate.